# Bootstrap 3 disable iPad Portrait

Tags: ipad, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

my question is about Twitter Bootstrap 3 - i'm using the Download Version from "getbootstrap.com", not the less/scss version.

I would like to disable only 1 media query (iPad Portrait).
Does anyone know, how to disable the Media-Query for iPad Portrait?
I would like to usw iPhone Media Query, on iPad Portrait i would like to zoom out the Browser so i can see the "md"-Version (Medium Desktop).

Or is it only possible via JavaScript (Changing Viewport an Zoom),
then i would try it this way - but i think there are a better solution, via CSS and Media queries.

best regards